# Checkbox when clicked does not show text fields. collapse not working

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have this checkbox that when clicked doesn't show the text area I want to implement in collapse such that when the checkbox is clicked I want to see the content. the checkbox does not show the content when it's clicked

```
import React from 'react';
import { Grid, FormControlLabel, Checkbox} from '@mui/material';
import { Collapse } from 'react-collapse';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import MyTextField from './MyTextField';
let defaultInitialIngestObject = {
  pushEnabled: true
}
export default function App(props) {
  const { initialValues } = props
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: Boolean(initialValues) ? initialValues : defaultInitialIngestObject,

  });
  return (
    <div>

      <Grid item xs={12}>
      
          <Grid item xs={4}>
            <FormControlLabel
              style={{ margin: 0, padding: 0, marginTop: '8px', verticalAlign: 'top' }}
              label="Submit"
              id="sub"
              control={

                < Checkbox size="large"
                  onClick={(evt) => formik.setFieldValue("sub", evt.target.checked)}
                  checked={formik.values['sub']}
                />
              }
            />
          </Grid>

          <Collapse in={formik.values.sub}>
            <Grid item xs={4}>

              <MyTextField
                disabled={formik.values.sub}
                id="firs"
                label="First"
                formik={formik}
              />
            </Grid>
          </Collapse>

        </Grid>
  
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things needing adjustment.
First, you are trying to change an uncontrolled input to be controlled
causing this warning in the console
`Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled. This is likely caused by the value changing from undefined to a defined value, which should not happen. Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.`

Let's address the issues.

- The reason the warning it's happening is that you are mounting the input with a value of undefined, then later when you click on it you are setting a value of true [checked]. 
  This will cause the error above, so lets predefine the value to be
  false [unchecked]

  ```js
     checked={formik.values.sub || false}
  ```
- Second, according to MUI Checkbox docs, the proper API is not `onClick` but `onChange` https://mui.com/material-ui/api/form-control-label/ , so, lets update that

  ```js
     onChange={
        (evt) => formik.setFieldValue("sub", evt.target.checked)
     }
  ```
- Third, the property `in` doesn't seem to be in the API according to the library docs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-collapse 
  I changed it to `isOpened` and now it works.

  ```
     <Collapse 
      // in={formik.values.sub}
      isOpened={formik.values.sub}
     >
  ```

I've created a sandbox here with a working version. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-example-checkbox-expand-8o2wzk?file=/src/App.js

PS. for your next issue, please provide a sandbox to make it easier for other to help out.